# How can I create an app as full screen in all android devices and without additional tools like the Navigation bar in android

Tags: android

I use the `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` for setting the layout as the full screen and without a `Title Bar`. But now I have a problem. some android devices have the additional tools  like the  Navigation bar and when I run my app in the devices, because there are the additional tools  like the  Navigation bar in the android devices, as the result my app is not `Full Screen` really and I see the Navigation bar still. Are there a way to solve this problem? How Can I create my app as Full Screen in all version of the android (API 7 to higher) really?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can force notification bar like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

But the Navigation Bar is not going to go... only on API lvl 19+ (4.4+) and it's called "Immersive mode". You can hide it and show it like this:

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

For more info, check the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html